# Reading a subset of documents using Couchbase View

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchbase

I have around 25M documents in my cluster. I need to read 1M documents at a time without any specific criterion. I don't have the access to the keys. So I need to create a view which will emit documents till I reach a counter which goes up to 1M.

I have written a Map function inside which I am trying to create a static variable, but JS doesn't support static variables. I am not sure how to do this operation. The map function which I have written is just to return 1000 documents and it is full of errors. Can someone help me with this functionality?

```
function (doc, meta) {
  value = foo();
  if(value < 1000)
  {
    emit(meta.id, null);
  }else{
    return;       
  }
}

function incrementor(){
  if(typeof incrementor.counter == 'undefined'){
       incrementor.counter = 0; 
  }

  return ++incrementor.counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a subset of documents with Views can be done using pagination: http://blog.couchbase.com/pagination-couchbase
The Map function is called for each mutation stored in the bucket so a counter approach like this does not make sense. If you want to split your indexes, you need to do that based on the content of the document. But you should really use pagination. This can also be achieved with N1Ql by the way.

Comment: Yes. Pagination solved my problem. Thanks a lot for helping me out.